# Modular addition in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate

I want to implement the Jordan gradient estimation algorithm in Qiskit. I need a unitary operator $U_f$ that performs as follows:
$$U_f:  |x_1\rangle |x_2\rangle \cdots |x_d\rangle|y\rangle \rightarrow |x_1\rangle |x_2\rangle \cdots |x_d\rangle|y \oplus f(x_1, \dots, x_d) \rangle.$$
Assuming a linear function of $f(x_1, \dots, x_d)$, is there any way to do this operation in Qiskit?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Please provide additional details. How does the function look like? What you provided is a general description how any Boolean functions is implemented on a quantum computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qiskit has an arithmetic circuit library that allows to do additions and multiplications, which allows you to implement a linear function $f$. A modular addition is also supported, simply by omitting the leading bit, which is for example supported in the [`DraperQFTAdder`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.DraperQFTAdder.html) by fixing the qubit register size using `kind="fixed"`.

However you will have to construct the circuit to implement the function manually, there is currently no support for parsing a linear function and generating the corresponding circuit.